# How to Modify Columns after clicking "Show data point as a table"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Users are looking for specific columns after right clicking on a bar chart to 'Show data point as a table'.

[image]

I tried modifying the columns in Power BI Desktop after right clicking on the bar chart, but they keep going back to these default columns. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. Can you include relevant screen shots?

Comment: It seems Power BI doesn't like date fields when you drill down. Thus, I converted the field the user wanted to text, and it was able to pull in after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove fields from this view, you need to 'Hide' them in Power BI Desktop.

For some weird reason, Date Fields don't come in to "Show data point as a table". To resolve, duplicate the desired date field and make it Text.